# Writing a function with date and time

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am new to R and programming in general and am looking for help with writing a function with dates and times. I have checked around but am still a bit stuck.

Basically, I have dates in the format "dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM" and I have to calculate how much time has passed between various events.

I have given the following command (where "date" is the column in my data frame that indicates the date and time in the above format):

```
date=as.Date.factor(date,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

However, this displays only the date, without the time.

I also have tried:

```
date=substr(argo1$date,1,907)
```

And it shows the date and time.

However, when I try to find the difference between two dates i.e.the time that has passed with the command: `difftime(date[2],date[3],unit="secs")`, it returns that 0 seconds have passed.

When I try to find the difference with the command:

```
date[3]-date[2]
```

it tells me

> Error in date[3] - date[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

The class(date) is "character".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You just asked the same question on r-help. Cross-posting is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Try `strptime`:

```
date1 = "30/12/2009 11:59"
date2 = "30/12/2009 12:03"
d1 = strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
d2 = strptime(date2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
difftime(d1, d2, unit="secs")
# Time difference of -240 secs
```